# Can't add mongodb to PATH variable on windows 7

Tags: windows, mongodb, path

I tried to add the mongodb programs on my windows 7 latop to run a few programs I'm working on.

I added the mongodb path to the end of windows PATH variable in system properties / advanced. This is what I have:

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\RSA SecurID Token Common;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Dell\Dell Data Protection\Encryption\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\tdunphy\bin;C:\Python27;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;%systemroot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Users\tdunphy\bin\;C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone;C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin
```

And when I try to run the mongo programs, this is what I get:

```
mongod' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

operable program or batch file.

```
mongo
'mongo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you restarted the shell/cmd ?

Comment: I've restarted the whole machine since I posted this yesterday. I still get the same result! `mongodb
'mongodb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`. Odd.

Comment: Paste your path to the bin folder. Make sure it ends with a \

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same situation moments ago. What I did was backup my PATH variable and put only the MongoDB path there. Restarted CLI and it worked. Then I added the deleted paths. Don't know why this worked.

By the way, 'mongodb' will not work, it's mongo or mongod depending what you want to call.